# User comment Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using Facebook's API and I need the userID of the person who comments a post. I tried `field=from`, but it gives me nothing.I'm using HTTPS requests only for now. Facebook's documentation says `from` return the user who writes the comment. Has someone tried this before ? Is it a bug ? I think it's because the person has a private profile but i'm not sure. Thanks.

Comment: where is your implementation code?

Comment: Actually, im using HTTPS request, not sdks or any code

Comment: Making HTTPS requests still require codes, isn't it? If the profile is private, you cannot obtain the information via Graph API. This is not how Graph API works.

Comment: That's what i needed to know, ty ! (and your right, HTTPS request is code)